# How can I know what is the maximum bullet capacity of a gun?

Tags: the-last-of-us

How can I know what is the maximum bullet capacity of a gun ? I would want shoot with a gun that has reached the maximum capacity. Like this, next time I find ammo for this gun, I will not waste them by not picking them.

Comment: I'm not sure extending the magazine size actually increases the amount of ammo you can carry, been a while since I've played though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [Last of Us Wiki](http://thelastofus.wikia.com/wiki/9mm_Pistol) to get info of maximum bullet capacity of a weapons. And according [this forum](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/652686-the-last-of-us/66495504) and my personal memory, each magazin upgrade adds one more bullet to maximum capacity (or maybe a little bit more, maximum bullets of unupgraded weapon plus bullets in magazine).